# Selenium C# Scrolling and clicking - web element

Tags: c#, selenium, scrollview, selenium-chromedriver

**What should the program do?** Click on every Button on the site.

[image]

```
By bybut = By.XPath("//span[@class='Button']");

var element = driver.FindElement(bybut);

IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
{
    // Scroll element into view (orange rectangle on my picture)
    js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

    // Time for scrolling
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

    // Click on Button
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='Button']")).Click();
}
```

On the internet site, if you click on the button, it will be removed.

**My Problem:**
If the For-Loop repeated, it comes to an error, because the next button is already in my view frame. How can I check, if a button is already into view?

Do you have any other solutions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can try below code :_

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;

    List<WebElement> displayedOptions = driver.FindElements(//span[@class='Button']);

    for (WebElement option : displayedOptions) 
     {
    try{

     js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", option );

     System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Click on Button
        driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@class='Button']")).Click();


    }catch(WebException E){


    }
```

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: "element not visible"

Comment: I rewritten a little bit my code and now it works! Thanks for your help!